# Not able to reload Nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, server

$ systemctl status nginx.service

● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-01-22 15:34:55 IST; 18min ago
  Process: 51312 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 51324 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 22 15:34:55 beta-app2 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...

Jan 22 15:34:55 beta-app2 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.

Jan 22 15:48:48 beta-app2 systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.

Jan 22 15:50:18 beta-app2 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Reload operation timed out. Killing reload process.

Jan 22 15:50:18 beta-app2 systemd[1]: Reload failed for A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.

**Please find the logs we are not able to reload Nginx. As we checked the file with the command "sudo nginx -t" and getting successful logs.But still we are getting this error. Please assist me to fix this.**

Comment: Have you already seen this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/443775/nginx-failing-to-reload-how-to-track-down-why

Comment: Yes I have done this step but didn't get any thing wrong with nginx.conf file.

Comment: What else have you tried?

Comment: I have tried every possible things but can not succeed. but getting this error in status:-
Start-pre operation timed out. Terminating.
Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
nginx.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.

Comment: I would be helpful to know which exact commands you have tried and include this information in your question

Comment: I have tried "sudo nginx -t" and got ok on my conf file. Then I tried sudo service nginx reload then it showing an error and i.e. Job for nginx.service failed because a timeout was exceeded

Comment: You could also try to restart nginx rather than reloading; does `sudo journalctl -u nginx.service` provide any useful logs?

Comment: Yes I have tried this as well. and this journalctl command gave me some error please find error below:-
Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
nginx.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
nginx.service: Start-pre operation timed out. Terminating.
Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.